# Coalesce operator alternative in Haskell

Tags: haskell, coalesce

I am receiving 2 string path's as an argument: `input` and `output` and i want to read the file from `input` path and write it to the `output` path.
I want to treat all 4 scenarios regarding input / output paths.When one of them is null i want to give it a default value.Is there anything like a coalesce operator?I do not want to rewrite the do clause for all scenarios:

Scenarios

```
 func   null _  -> {do clause}
        _ null  -> {do clause}
        _  _   ->  {do clause}
        x  y   ->  {do clause}

let defaultInPath="inPath.txt"
    defaultOutPath="outPath.txt"
```

What i want to achieve -do clause:

```
  do 
    text<-readFile input??defaultIn
    writeFile  output??defaultOut text
    return text
```

P.S I am new to Haskell and i am really trying to get a grasp of it.

Comment: How are you receiving the values? Are they in a list you need to unpack or `Maybe String` values?

Comment: This question isn't clear, but you might be looking for the `Maybe` monad. [The LYAH chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads) might help you.

Comment: I am reading from a text file.It should be [String]

Comment: Haskell doesn't have null references, so what exactly do you mean by 'null'. An empty list? Is that the only thing you wish to handle? How about  file names that are proper strings, but where the file doesn't exist?

Comment: By null i meant empty string .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use the `Maybe` type constructor

First, encode your "null" strings correctly using `Maybe`. Then, use the `maybe` function to return your default values if an argument is `Nothing`.

```
func :: Maybe String -> Maybe String -> IO String
func inFile outFile = do
   text <- readFile $ maybe defaultIn id inFile
   writeFile (maybe defaultOut id outFile) text
   return text
```

### Using `Data.Maybe`

If you don't mind an extra import, you can use `fromMaybe d = maybe d id`.

```
import Data.Maybe

func :: Maybe String -> Maybe String -> IO String
func inFile outFile = do
   text <- readFile $ fromMaybe defaultIn inFile
   writeFile (fromMaybe defaultOut outFile) text
   return text
```

### Defining `??` yourself

Either way, you can define your own coalescing operator from either function:

```
?? :: Maybe String -> String -> String
(??) = flip fromMaybe
-- a ?? b = fromMaybe b a
-- a ?? b = maybe b id a
```

and write

```
func inFile outFile = do
    text <- readFile (inFile ?? defaultIn)
    writeFile (outFile ?? defaultOut) text
    return text
```

### Using `Maybe`

Your four types of calls would look like this, assuming you aren't already
getting the values from a function that returns a `Maybe String` value.

```
func Nothing Nothing
func (Just "input.txt") Nothing
func Nothing (Just "output.txt")
func (Just "input.txt") (Just "output.txt")
```

Comment: There's also `fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a`

Comment: Thanks; that's the one that was rattling around in the back of my mind.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers already here are more practical than what follows, but if you're interested in a more conceptual view of things, then read on.

First, Haskell doesn't have null references, but if you want to model missing values, you can use `Maybe`. If, for example, you want to treat the empty string as a missing value, you can write a conversion function like this:

```
maybeFromNull :: Foldable t => t a -> Maybe (t a)
maybeFromNull xs = if null xs then Nothing else Just xs
```

You use it like this:

```
*Q49616294> maybeFromNull "foo"
Just "foo"
*Q49616294> maybeFromNull ""
Nothing
```

The reason that this is interesting when the talk falls on null coalescing operators in Haskell is that [there's a monoid over Maybe that corresponds to that](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/04/03/maybe-monoids). It's called `First`, and it returns the leftmost non-`Nothing` value from a series of candidates.

For reasons that may be clearer later, I'll use the one from `Data.Semigroup`, so

```
import Data.Semigroup
```

In order to get the `Monoid` behaviour over `Maybe`, you need to wrap the `First` value in an `Option`; e.g.:

```
*Q49616294> (Option $ Just $ First 42) <> (Option $ Just $ First 1337)
Option {getOption = Just (First {getFirst = 42})}
```

Granted, that's quite a long-winded way to select the left-most value, but highlights that null coalesce is 'just' a monoid:

```
*Q49616294> (Option $ Just $ First 42) <> (Option Nothing)
Option {getOption = Just (First {getFirst = 42})}
*Q49616294> (Option Nothing) <> (Option $ Just $ First 1337)
Option {getOption = Just (First {getFirst = 1337})}
```

Since that's too verbose for practical use, you could decide to write a custom operator that repackages `Maybe` values as `Option First` values, applies the `<>` operations, and then unwraps the result from `Option First` back to `Maybe`:

```
(<?>) :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
mx <?> my =
  let ofx = Option $ sequenceA $ First mx
      ofy = Option $ sequenceA $ First my
      leftmost = ofx <> ofy
  in getFirst $ sequenceA $ getOption $ leftmost
```

While you could write this operator as one big expression, I chose to use the `let...in` syntax to 'show my work'.

One problem remains, though:

```
*Q49616294> Just 42 <?> Just 1337
Just 42
*Q49616294> Nothing <?> Nothing
Nothing
```

While the operation returns a `Just` value as long as at least one of the arguments is a `Just` value, it *can* return `Nothing`.

How do you apply a fallback value so that you're guaranteed to get a value in all cases?

You can take advantage of `Option` being `Foldable`, and then still fold over `<>` - only this time, a different `Monoid` instance is in use:

```
(<!>) :: Maybe a -> a -> a
mx <!> y =
  let ofx = Option $ sequenceA $ First mx
      fy  = First y
  in getFirst $ foldr (<>) fy ofx
```

This operator folds over `ofx`, using `fy` as an initial value. Here, `<>` belongs to the `First` `Semigroup`, which unconditionally returns the leftmost value. There's no `Option` involved here, since `foldr` peels that layer away. Since we're folding from the right, though, the initial value `fy` will always be ignored if `ofx` contains a value.

```
*Q49616294> Just 42 <!> 1337
42
*Q49616294> Nothing <!> 1337
1337
```

You can now write the desired function as follows:

```
copyFile :: String -> String -> IO String
copyFile input output = do
  text <- readFile $ (maybeFromNull input) <!> defaultInPath
  writeFile (maybeFromNull output <!> defaultOutPath) text
  return text
```

It turns out that in this case, you don't even need `<?>`, but in other situations, you could use this operator to chain as many potential values as you'd like:

```
*Q49616294> Just 42 <?> Nothing <?> Just 1337 <!> 123
42
*Q49616294> Nothing <?> Nothing <?> Just 1337 <!> 123
1337
*Q49616294> Nothing <?> Nothing <?> Nothing <!> 123
123
```

Not only is this way of implementing null coalescing behaviour needlessly complicated, I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't perform well to add spite to injury.

It does, however, illustrate the power and expressivity of Haskell's built-in abstractions.

Comment: Thank you for your thoroughly answer sir.

Comment: @mark-seemann "this way of implementing null coalescing behaviour needlessly complicated" - Can you elaborate on that?
Does this mean that c# null coalescing operators ? and ?? are also "needlessly complicated".
What is the alternative - Never aggregating Maybe monad?

Comment: @SeeR As I wrote, the *"other answers already here are more practical"*. See those for much simpler solutions.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Oh. So I was reading too much from this sentence. It was nothing against ?? operator, just that there are simpler implementations (like the one using fromMaybe). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have a value that may or may not be provided, you should definitely encode this safely and flexibly with Maybe.

However, if you really want to replace an empty string or any other magic value, you can easily use `if..then..else` as an expression:

```
func :: String -> IO ()
func input = do 
  text <- readFile (if input == "" then defaultIn else input) 
  putStrLn text
```

and of course, once you do switch to Maybe and find yourself with a plain string, you can use the same to call it:

```
func :: Maybe String -> IO ()
func input = do
  text <- readFile $ fromMaybe "default.txt" input 
  putStrLn text

main = do
  putStrLn "Enter filename or blank for default:"
  file <- getLine
  func (if file == "" then Nothing else Just file)
```